# Populating collection onto UI using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, chat

I am building a chat application using JSP, Servlets and Ajax with Smack API. Once the user connects to Gtalk his buddies list should be displayed onto the UI. I am able to get the buddies list onto console but populating it on the JSP is giving problems.

In my servlet I get the buddy list using:

```
  Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
    for(RosterEntry r:entries)
    {
        String user = r.getUser();
        pw.println(user);
    }
```

In my jsp page I want the buddy list to be populated on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {

               document.getElementById(buddies).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }

    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","LoginIMServlet",true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
)
<table>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <form name=ListForm>
    <select id="buddies" name="buddies" size=40 multiple onclick="window.open("ChatWindow.jsp",width=500,height=350,resizable=yes")>
    </select>
     </form> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am not able to populate the multi selector box. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do server-side stuff during page load, you don't necessarily need JS/Ajax for this. You can just let JSP do the job. This saves the cost of one more HTTP request.

Let the servlet's `doGet()` method store it in request scope and forward to JSP.

```
Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
request.setAttribute("rosterEntries", roster.getEntries());
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Let the JSP utilize JSTL `<c:forEach>` to iterate over it and print the `<option>` elements.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<select multiple>
    <c:forEach items="${rosterEntries}" var="rosterEntry">
        <option>${fn:escapeXml(rosterEntry.user)}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

*(the `fn:escapeXml()` is not mandatory, but it just prevents you from potential XSS attack holes)*

Now call the URL of servlet instead of the JSP one. JSP will populate it "on page load".

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, if you're using jQuery, then you should not create `XMLHttpRequest` objects yourself. This makes no utter sense. Just use `$.ajax()`, `$.get()`, etc functions. For examples, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/update-current-page-with-a-servlet).

If you *really* want to solve this with jQuery, then best is to let the servlet return the data as JSON and use `$.getJSON()` to retrieve it. Do the following in the `doGet()` method instead:

```
Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
String rosterEntriesJson = new Gson().toJson(roster.getEntries());
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(rosterEntriesJson);
```

*(Gson is here [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), just download and drop JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`)*

Map this servlet on `/buddies` and do the following in JSP/jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('buddies', function(rosterEntriesJson) {
            var $buddies = $('#buddies');
            $.each(rosterEntriesJson, function(index, rosterEntry) {
                $('<option>').text(rosterEntry.user).appendTo($buddies);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
...
<select id="buddies" multiple></select>
```

Comment: Hey BalusC... I tries ur solution 2 i get an error tellin java.lang.IllegalStateException: How can the type variable not be present in the class declaration!                                      wher am i goin wrong???

Comment: You have another code in the method block which is causing that. Probably you're unnecessarily calling `getOutputStream()`, probably you're unnecessarily calling `forward()`, etc. The real answer is in the stacktrace which you got. At least, you shouldn't do anything else than the given example, expect initializing the `connection`.